# Prepare loading spinner waiting for variable to be filled up

Tags: angular, typescript

I've made some function to display a list. When I try to pass the big data to a variable however it takes too much time to load. For my case, the `this.data_chapters` variable lead my app to be slower in performance.

How do I implement something like prepare *Loading Spinner* (waiting for a variable to be filled) in order to notify the user for the process before it done?

```
displayChapterList(chapterLessonData,scode_id,colourCode)
{

    //.. some codes

    //Very big data need to be pass to data_chapters
    this.data_chapters = chapterLessonData; // Very large data
    set_alarmed("Done!");
}

set_alarmed(msg)
{ 
    alert(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can leverage HTTP interceptors. When any request is made, increment the request count. When a request completes (or errors) decrement the request count.  Use `ngIf` to display a spinner component when the number of pending requests > 0.

**RequestHttpInterceptor.ts**

```
import { HttpInterceptor } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpRequest } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";

import 'rxjs/add/operator/finally'

import { HttpMonitor } from "../request-spinner/http.monitor";

export class RequestHttpInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(private httpMonitor: HttpMonitor){

    }
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
       this.httpMonitor.addRequest();
        return next.handle(req).finally(() => {
            this.httpMonitor.removeRequest();
        })

    }
}
```

**http.monitor.ts**

The `HttpMonitor` is a service that keeps track of pending requests. An event is emitted whenever the request is incremented or decremented.

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
export class HttpMonitor {
    public pendingRequestNumber: number;
    public pendingRequests:Observable<number>;
    private prSubject: BehaviorSubject<number>;

    constructor() {
        this.prSubject = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);
        this.pendingRequests = this.prSubject.asObservable();
        this.pendingRequestNumber = 0;
    }

    addRequest() {
        this.prSubject.next(++this.pendingRequestNumber)
    }
    removeRequest() {
        this.prSubject.next(--this.pendingRequestNumber)
    }
}
```

**spinner.component.ts**

Create a spinner component that listens for pending request events from the `HttpMonitor`:

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { HttpMonitor } from './http.monitor';

@Component({
    selector: '[spinner]',
    template: `
        <img *ngIf="httpMonitor.pendingRequestNumber >0" src="http://www.silkron.co.uk/images/spinner.gif" />
    `,
    styles: [
        `
            img {
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
            }
        `
    ]
})
export class SpinnerComponent {
    constructor(public httpMonitor:HttpMonitor){

    }

}
```

**app.module.ts**

Register the service with the AppModule (spinner should probably go in a shared module).  Here, the service and spinner component are in the same module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpMonitor } from "./request-spinner/http.monitor";
import { SpinnerComponent } from "./request-spinner/spinner.component";
import {HTTP_INTERCEPTORS} from '@angular/common/http';
import { RequestHttpInterceptor } from "./interceptors/request.interceptor";

@NgModule({
  imports: [BrowserModule, HttpClientModule],
  declarations: [AppComponent, SpinnerComponent],
  exports: [AppComponent],
  providers: [
    HttpMonitor,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: RequestHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true,
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Place the spinner where you want it to show in one of your component templates:

```
<span spinner></span>
```

Comment: I got this problem..
`Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for RequestHttpInterceptor: (?).`

Comment: You have to add the HttpMonitor to the providers array

Answer (score 0):

You can do this adding svg loader in your html component :

```
<img *ngIf="loading" src="data:image/gif;base64,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"/>
```

And in your ts controler define a var :

```
  loading = false;
```

When you start your function :

```
this.loading = true;
```

and after :

```
this.loading = false;
```

Comment: How do I use before send like in ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I am using following solution for my angular 2 applications successfully.Add following html to inside the body tag of index.html

```
<body>
  <div id="preloader" class="loader" style="display: none">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center" style="height: 100%;">
      <div class="loader-content" title="0">
        Progress Bar Loading ....
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
  <app-root class="">Loading...</app-root>
</body>
```

instead of `Progress bar loading...` text you can use any html to show your progress bar html. Keep it hidden using `style="display: none"`

Write a service to show and hide the preloader div as follows.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class PreloaderService {

  static showPreLoader() {
    document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'block';
  }
  static hidePreLoader() {
    document.getElementById('preloader').style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

Use it as follows inside your components.

```
import { PreloaderService } from '../../../shared/services/preloader.service';
```

This service has two static methods, use to show and hide preloader. No needs to give this service as a constructor parameter to use those methods.

Just before the HTTP request

Show

```
PreloaderService.showPreLoader();
```

After got the result

Hide

```
PreloaderService.hidePreLoader();
```

Comment: No http request..just big data in a variable need to pass.